# decode every file in a zip file with python

Tags: python, decode

I have a zip file [file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpEns38Vwj1FnIhdm_iRBijTybLMq2J9/view?usp=sharing)

it is encoded with utf-8 code, how can I decode every file within it? I tried but failed: TypeError: decoding with 'utf-8' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ZipFile')

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import codecs

with ZipFile('articles.zip', 'r') as zip:
    with zip.open('articles/document0001.txt') as file:
       codecs.decode(file, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict')
```

also there are 100 files on that Zip, any smart way to do the decoding for all the files in one off?

Comment: I think you want `zip.open()` or `zip.extract()` or `zip.extractall()`, check out the methods on the `ZipFile` class: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects

Comment: @alkasm I tried them and they do the extract and open, but the problem is I wanna decode the files one off

Comment: Instead of `zip.open(...)`, you can use [`zip.read(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read) to get the bytes directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on the text:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('articles.zip', 'r') as z:
    with z.open('articles/document0001.txt') as file:
        file_text = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(file_text)  # or do whatever else you want to do with it.
```

Comment: thank you! also if i have 100 txt files in that zip, do I need to repeat the with z.open('articles/document0001.txt') as file:
        file_text = file.read().decode('utf-8')
        print(file_text)
100 times? any easier ways? thanks!

Comment: You can loop over them, if you need help with that, I suggest opening a new question!